# notifyjs notification is not working with position of an element

Tags: notifyjs

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="notify/js/notify.js"></script>
<script src="notify/js/notify-bootstrap.js"></script>
<form>
    <div  id="userInfoDiv" name="userInfoDiv" style="padding-top:100px;padding-left:100px;">

    <span class="box pos-demo">Notifyjs position div</span>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".pos-demo").notify(
"Welcome Guest", 
{ position:"right" }
);
$.notify("This notofication is working ","success");
</script>
```

Note : The notification is not displayed.Where as $,notify("") without position is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Though I cannot confirm this the cause I think its because at the time of the notification, the elements do not actually exist in the DOM (the web page), so there is nothing for the element to tie to. It fails silently, I used the Google developer tools and could see no error being generated.

My solution. If you create a function and call in body.onload the element appears. e.g

```
<body onload="notifyme();">
```

And then somewhere in the page (at the bottom perhaps)

```
<script>
    function notifyme() {
        var s = "Hello";

        $("#myelem").notify(s);
    }
</script>
```

I know this works a I have just tried it. Works every time, every page.